# How to Use PostThreadMessage() (Unexpected Results)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

First, I'm new to multithreading. So, if there is a better way than my approach I would like to hear.

I'm injecting my code into another process. I created a CBT hook to get notified when new windows are created. When my target window created, I get notification by CBT hook and create a thread, and at the end this thread calls PostThreadMessage() function to send data/notification to another thread of me (which is inside same/target application, too).

But this doesn't work as expected. My receiving thread gets that message 4 times before I even send it first. Then after I send it, it doesn't get it this time.
Let's come to code.

This is how I create receiver thread.

```
#define MM_MY_MESSAGE (WM_APP)
// Also tried with different macros
// #define MM_MY_MESSAGE (WM_APP + 999)
// #define MM_MY_MESSAGE (WM_USER)
// #define MM_MY_MESSAGE (WM_USER + 999)

gReceiverThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadReceiver, NULL, 0, &gReceiverThreadId);
// global variables
```

This is my receiver thread, which also uses WM_COPYDATA messages.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadReceiver(LPVOID lpParam) {

    MSG msg;

    HWND hwndReceiver = CreateReceiverWindow();
    // If necessary I can post this function later
    // This window is created for WM_COPYDATA messages
    // Not important for PostThreadMessage()

    if (!hwndReceiver) {
        std::cout << "Receiver window can not be created!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

This is WndProc for WM_COPYDATA and MM_MY_MESSAGE.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ReceiverWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(message) {

        case WM_COPYDATA:

            // do something
            break;
        case MM_MY_MESSAGE:

            std::cout << "PostThreadMessage received" << std::endl;
            return 0;


    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This is how I call PostThreadMessage():

```
DWORD WINAPI AnotherThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
    // This thread gets created inside CBT hook which is unrelated
    // etc.
    PostThreadMessage(gReceiverThreadId, MM_MY_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << "PostThreadMessage send" << std::endl;
    // etc
    return 0;
}
```

After I run my code, output shows,

```
PostThreadMessage received
PostThreadMessage received
PostThreadMessage received
PostThreadMessage received
PostThreadMessage send
```

This is clearly not what I wanted. What is wrong here?

Comment: `PostThreadMessage()` posts a message to a *thread*, not to a *window*. You would handle a thread message directly in your `GetMessage()` loop, not in a window procedure. However, there are subtleties with using `PostThreadMessage()` on a thread with UI: [any thread that does anything with an implied modal loop loses the message](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050427-10/?p=35763). The solution is simple: use `PostMessage()` to post the message to your window instead. `PostMessage()` will automatically send the message to the correct thread.

Comment: *How to use PostThreadMessage?* Don't.

Comment: The output is easy to explain, because you don't output until _after_.  The sender thread goes to sleep before finishing (or even starting) the `cout` call.  The repeated messages are harder to explain.  It's not clear you've followed all the guidelines outlined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx), especially in the _Remarks_ section.

Comment: @paddy MSDN says; _It returns without waiting for the thread to process the message._ [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Yes, but all that means is that it doesn't block until the other thread receives the message.  _i.e._ you cannot guarantee any stack data passed via the message will be valid at the receiving end.  It does _not_ stop the operating system from suspending your thread and/or in any other way servicing the receiving thread before executing the `cout` call.

Comment: @andlabs I changed it to `PostMessage()`. Now it first outputs 'send' then 'received'. This part is solved. But at first, it still outputs 'received' 4 times before I send.

Comment: @andlabs is it possible, target program broadcast or send its all threads a message which is same with my define statement. I'm totally guessing it could be nonsense. but i can't think any other possibility for now.

Comment: No, you've not solved anything. The message could be received and processed before `PostMessage` returns. You cannot expect any ordering on the output.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan actually it doesn't matter right now. I'm not sending any data. So, if receiver processes before, it doesn't change anything. But for curiosity, if it needs to be ordered, can I do that? And if yes how?

Comment: Order using a synchronization object. For instance an event.

Comment: If you want to test whether your message is being used already, just send some custom values via `wParam` and `lParam`, and display them when you process.  It's unlikely that the other messages will use _your_ values if there's a conflict.

Comment: @paddy it's solved now thanks. it was a mistake in my code. But, I wonder which range should I use in this situation; `WM_USER` or `WM_APP`?

Comment: *"it was a mistake in my code"* - code you didn't show us. Always show the real code when asking for help.

Comment: I think you should use an offset from `WM_APP`, although you still need to be careful because you're injecting into another process.  In any case, read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx